# Why Html.Action fails while not finding controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in asp.net-MVC and it's my first MVC app.

I have a controller linked to a partial view : (_UtilisateurController.cs) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Mvc_LanceurBatch.BLL;
using Mvc_LanceurBatch.DTO;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;


namespace Mvc_LanceurBatch.Controllers
{
    public class _UtilisateurController : Controller
    {
        LanceurBatchDLL _oLanceurBatchDLL = new LanceurBatchDLL();

        public ActionResult Utilisateur()
        {
            
            List<UtilisateurDTO> oListUtilisateur = _oLanceurBatchDLL.GetUtilisateur("", "").ToList();

            return View(oListUtilisateur);
        }       
    }
}
```

Partial view (_Utilisateur.cshtml) :

```
@using Mvc_LanceurBatch.D TO
@model Mvc_LanceurBatch.DTO.UtilisateurDTO

    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.LI_LOGIN, new SelectList(Model.Utilisateurs, "LI_LOGIN", "NOM"), "Sélectionner un utilisateur")
        <input id="ButtonReinit" type="Button" value="Réinitialiser" />
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("#LI_LOGIN").change(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '@Url.Action("RechercheDemande")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { "Login": $(this).val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#divDemande").html(result);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

And my main view (LanceurBatch.cshtml) :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lanceur de batch";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@*@@using (Html.BeginForm("RechercheDemande", "LanceurBatch", FormMethod.Post))*@
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RechercheDemande", "LanceurBatch", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "divPartial",
}))
{

            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.Action("Utilisateur", "Mvc_LanceurBatch.Controllers._UtilisateurController")
               
                <br/>
                <br />
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="divPartial">
                    <label></label>
               
                     @Html.Action("RechercheDemande")
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

When I run the app, my main view (LanceurBatch.cshtml) fails at the line: @Html.Action("Utilisateur",...

The error is:

> The controller for the path « /LanceurBatch/LanceurBatch » cannot be found or doesn't implement IController.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Why do you prefix your controller with an underscore?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC uses conventions to find things. So, by default, if given a URL like `/Home/Index` it looks for a controller named `HomeController` and a method on that controller named `Index`. When using `Html.Action`, it does a similar lookup strategy.

Comment: gunr2171 : I have prefixed it with underscore because it's a partial view.
Heretic Monkey : I tried every path for the html.Action but none has succeeded.

Comment: Don't use the underscore there. Take a look at coding conventions from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions

Comment: Paul : thank you for your link. But despite the conventions names, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found what's wrong.
I have renamed the view and the controller without underscores.
In the view LanceurBatch.cshtml I have modified :

```
@Html.Action("Utilisateur", "Utilisateur")
```

In the controller UtilisateurController.cs :

```
return PartialView("~/Views/LanceurBatch/Utilisateur.cshtml", oUtilisateur);
```

And I have removed from the LanceurBatch.cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("RechercheDemande")
```